# how to convert from timezone 'fromTZ' to 'toTZ' using string fromTZ date?

Tags: java, date

How do I convert a datestring to a long? I expect the method signature will be `public static long convert2(String dateStr,TimeZone fromTz, TimeZone toTz)` where `dateStr` is in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Is this homework? What is the format of dateStr?

Comment: dateStr is in string format.. m getting it from user

Comment: That is the datatype. I mean is it "yyyy/mm/dd" is it "mm/dd/yy" is it "3:55pm on June 27th, 2012 CE", etc? Also, I suspect this is a homework assignment so I added the Homework tag. It doesn't help you if we just give you the answer but we can still give you advice.

Comment: ohk.. it is dd/MM/yyyy..

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? I don't understand how the timezones are useful unless the function is also given a time (i.e. 1am on 01/01/2012 in NYC is 10pm on 31/12/2011 in LA)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long convert2(String dateStr,TimeZone fromTz, TimeZone toTz)
// Format in which you are getting the date
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");  
// Set the formater to the timezone in which you are getting the date
formatter.setTimeZone(fromTz);  

// Converting the string date to date
Date date = formatter.parse(dateStr);

// Prints the date in the from time zone timezone. Not required as per the quest. Just for info  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));  

// Set the formatter to use a different timezone  
formatter.setTimeZone(toTz);  

// Prints the date in the to time zone timezone. Not required as per the quest. Just for info  
System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); 

// converting the new Timzone date to long as that is what is required
long longDate = date.getTime();

// return the long date.
return longDate;
```

Comment: @acattle - I thought the questioner would have some knowledge of Java. Anyway added a few more comments as you suggested.

Comment: actually, i wanted to convert the fromTz into toTz using dateStr...i.e from timezone fromTz to timezone toTz using string dateStr.. and above code is quite useful for that.. thanx